# What are the office codes on the 1911 Census?

Tags: england, 20th-century, census-records

This is a snippet I posted in a related question [Children born overseas to British Subjects — what is their citizenship status?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/6564/children-born-overseas-to-british-subjects-what-is-their-citizenship-status)

[image: 1911 Census Citizenship entry]

I've seen other codes on the 1911 Census forms in red and green ink.  What do the codes mean?

Answer (score 2):

Via a search of ukbmd.org.uk which was suggested by @ColeValleyGirl for another question, I found these links on FindMyPast:

- [Birthplace codes](http://www.findmypast.co.uk/content/expert-1911-birthplace-codes)
- [Occupation codes](http://www.findmypast.co.uk/content/expert-1911-occupation-codes)

The key for the occupation codes also has a link to the [original occupation sheet on histpop](http://www.histpop.org/ohpr/servlet/PageBrowser?path=Browse/TNA%20Census%20-%20Other%20(by%20date)&active=yes&mno=3190&tocstate=expandnew&tocseq=1500&display=sections&display=tables&display=pagetitles&pageseq=first-nonblank&zoom=5).

The tally sheet for the birthplaces is image [10 of 14](http://www.histpop.org/ohpr/servlet/PageBrowser?path=Browse/TNA%20Census%20-%20Other%20%28by%20date%29&active=yes&mno=3190&tocstate=expandnew&display=sections&display=tables&display=pagetitles&pageseq=234&zoom=5) in that set of images on histpop.

Comment: As 1911census.co.uk is no longer online, I have updated the links to the equivalent pages on FMP